# Can I release Google Assistant Private App

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm developing a Google Assistant Action using Dialogflow.
When the development is completed, I want to release this Action to Assistant.

But this Action is purely for personal use, so I worry that the release is rejected.

Has anyone released a private Action?

I don't want Alpha or Beta version app, because these versions are included 'Test Version' phrases when the version load

Comment: To the person who downvoted this as off topic - the question is on-topic for programming and "software tools commonly used by programmers" developing for Actions on Google.

Answer (score 0):

If the Action is completely private (ie - just for you) then leaving it in an Alpha channel is most appropriate.

If the audience is broader, but still very limited, and you don't want to deal with the "test" phrase, and you are willing to have it reviewed, then you can limit access to it by using the [Google Sign In for Assistant](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in), which will give you a user ID which you can check against a whitelist.